# How can Devise users create an invitation for others to accept and start and able to finish invitation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an app in rails that has **User's** and that has **Dogwalkers**, these users are created on Devise. So, I wan't that a User is able to create a Dog walk for and set, date, time and add the dogs that are going to take for a walk.

I got my Dog's Database on Sqlite:

```
create_table :dogs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :photo
      t.string :race
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :dogs, [:user_id, :created_at]
```

And I got my Walks model:

```
class CreateWalks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :walks do |t|
      t.integer :walk_id
      t.date :walk_at
      t.datetime :walk_start_at
      t.datetime :walk_end_at
      t.integer :status
      t.references :dog, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :dogwalker, foreign_key: true
      t.float :dogprice
      t.integer :doglimit

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :walks, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

So how can I make that the user is able to create a Walk, and let the Dog walker able to see it on it's own dashboard (which I already created). The Dog Walker will accept it and it will send a notification to the user that it has been accept it. Once the user has received there dog's the walk has finish and create a history of the walk.

What I been doing:

1. Created the databases that I show above.
2. Made the views
3. Made the forms for the user able to create a new Dog trip
4. Created the controllers for the walk

Hope this possible! Thanks for you help!!!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: "So how can I make that the user is able to create a Walk, and let the Dog walker able to see it on it's own dashboard (which I already created). The Dog Walker will accept it and it will send a notification to the user that it has been accept it. Once the user has received there dog's the walk has finish and create a history of the walk."

Comment: That is, IMO, a very broad question. I'm not sure you'll get the help you're looking for. Perhaps you can narrow it down to your most immediate challenge/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is create a form for a new Walk. The user(dog owner) will fin the required fields, like date, walk_start_at and walk_end_at. Maybe some more, but that's up to you.

On the users dashboard(the dogwalker) you can list all walks that available by:
`@walks = Walk.where(dogwalker: nil)` This will give you all the walks that don't have a walker yet. For each of these walks you also add a form for walk that only needs a submit button. When the dogwalker hits the button it goes to the update action from the Walk. There you receive the params and you can set the dogwalker.

Now on the dogowner can see that the walk is accepted.

Comment: Yeah so basiclly that's what I want to do, that the dogwalker is able to see the walks for the normal users. AND that the dogwalker by a button can accept it. **Maybe showing the dogwalks to the dogwalker is no big deal for me, it's more How can the dog walker accept it?**

Comment: @kenSanchez like I said in my answer. By displaying a form on the dogwalker page with only a submit button that will update the walk by setting the dogwalker to the walk. If the dogwalker sets his id as dogwalker then that means it is accepted or do you have an other definition for accepting?

Btw you are answering your own question:
How can the dog walker accept it?
that the dogwalker by a button can accept it.